# should we have to add public key to .ssh/authorized_keys when login with same key pair?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I want to use same key pair on multiple machines to ssh each other. I have copied `.ssh/id_rsa` and `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` one machine to all other machines. Should I have to add `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `.ssh/authorized_keys` of all the machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SSH distinguishes authorized keys from keys it “knows” about.

`authorized_keys` is used by the [daemon](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd) to determine whether a key (offered by a connecting client) is allowed to access the host it’s running on.

`id_rsa` and other key files are used by the [client](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh) (by default, unless the `-i` option is given) as sources of keys to offer targets it’s trying to connect to.